# How to make best UI layout for Android App?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to make layout with animations on Card And Recycler View.

I want to show Card View list of data like Play Store App and show App detail layout.

So please give me some advice and reference link to learn about design layout and animations ?

Answer (score 0):

Following material design principles helps you build awesome interactive applications with meaningful animations. This is one of the most important thing in building a great user experience.

If you're looking for examples of awesome material design apps, here's the link
http://materialdesignblog.com/googles-material-design-utilized-in-mobile-web-data-visualization/

For understanding good material design principles, I found this course in Udacity to be a ton of help.
https://www.udacity.com/courses/ud862

For using material design guided pallets, icons, principles etc. this link is great https://design.google.com/resources/?gclid=COCBzKuO_MoCFcoTaAodpWcBog

Answer (score 0):

I find this tutorial very helpful. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465 Also, you might want to check or search about Coordinator Layouts and play with it! Good luck!